# WebElement is being returned as NoneType after calling driver.refresh()

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm writing a script in Python to do a smoke test on a social network, that implements a post feed.

I wrote a method that looks for the topmost post, and returns it (it's the class "media"). You'll see that there are some time.sleep() and refresh() calls, and that's because the server we use is horrible, to say the least, and the loading fails *very* often, only rendering partial content, making a refresh necessary.

Here's where the problem is: When, and only when the br.refresh() is called, the object returned is NoneType. If the page loads correctly, and the refresh() is not called, the object returned is correct.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen? I tried implementing the method without the use of exceptions (in case this is what broke the return, somehow) without any success.

PS: Curiously enough, if instead of waiting for the br.refresh() to be called, I manually go and press the Refresh button on the "driven" browser, the object is returned perfectly.

Here's the code:

```
def getLastPost (br, count = 0):

    try:
        elapsed = 0
        while(br.find_elements_by_class_name("media") == []) and elapsed < 15:
            if elapsed % 5 == 0:
                log("Waiting...","w")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            elapsed += 0.5
        if(br.find_elements_by_class_name("media") == []):
            raise NoSuchElementException
        return br.find_elements_by_class_name("media")[0]

    except NoSuchElementException:
        if(count >= 5):
            raise Exception("Element not found after 5 page reloads.")
        log("Element not loaded! Retrying.","w")
        count += 1
        br.refresh()
        time.sleep(count)  # Wait a bit more each time.
        getLastPost(br, count)
```

And the error that gives when trying to read the returned object:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Smoke.py", line 37, in <module>
    assert ("MESSAGE") in getLastPost(br).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`refresh()` reloads the browser page. After that, all `WebElement`s are invalid and you must locate them again.

Background: Selenium / WebDriver doesn't remember how you got the element, they ask the browser for a unique internal ID of the element and when you, say, click on an element, they sand a message to the browser "click on 34987563424563.34675".

A reload invalidates all internal IDs.

The reason why you get `None` in the assert is because there is no `return` statement in the `except` clause (last line). Without an explicit `return`, all Python functions return `None`. Try `return getLastPost(br, count)`

Comment: I understand that, but after refreshing, I call find_element... again,  it finds it, and returns it, as if it was a valid WebElement. If it was a Stale element, shouldn't the error come up before, and not after returning it and trying to read it?

Comment: Since you don't use the `br` between the "refresh" and "trying to read it", what exactly should trigger the error?

Comment: You are right, I expressed quite wrong. My doubt mostly is, why does it trigger a "NoneType" error instead of a Stale element? Shouldn't *that* error come up when trying to read the text property, instead of "hey, you are reading a 'void' object"? Many thanks for your patience!

Comment: Ah, that's because there is no `return` statement in the `except` clause (last line). Without an explicit `return`, all Python functions return `None`. Try `return getLastPost(br, count)`

Comment: AHA! That I didn't actually think about! And, it actually works! Thank you so much for your help!